# How to send force update to my *Pre-Installed* application users without new code implementation in android like Gmail?

Tags: android, auto-update

I checked **In-app updates**, **App Update via Remote-Config**, **Update via version check**. But these are not providing solution to what I want. I am also sending update notification to users. But some of users are not updating latest version of app.

So, I want to do force update that **"pre-installed"** old app without any new integration of code. Same **like Gmail is auto updating** in our android device.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: magically you cant have a force update unless you had implemented something to force your user to either update or quit the app

Comment: @Gautam, that is my question. How gmail is auto updating without any update information/notification ??

Comment: It's not auto-updating. Users have a choice to allow which apps should update automatically when connected over wifi and so on. Moreover, it's part of G suite i.e Gapps, which has more control than third party applications installed via playstore

Comment: if its like that, then how can i update app automatically without user interaction

Comment: that's totally up to the user which apps they want to update and which they don't. The only thing you can control is to introduce force update but that required code changes

Comment: Or if the company controls the device/uses a work profile via Android Work/mobile device management software to do silent app distribution: https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#3.5.-silent-app-distribution_1

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: @MorrisonChang can you please explain this in details?

Comment: If you are dealing with business devices those devices would have already been registered as owned by the company or have a work profile for secure business apps. In that case you can 'push' apps to those devices. See: https://developers.google.com/android/work Really only for businesses to secure the devices or data due to cost. You might want to restart your question explaining what/how the app was "pre-installed" and who owns the device.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Here i used word "pre-install" means actually app is installed from play store. But after updating app on playstore, some users are using only old version of app. so i want to force them for update app when they open app.

Comment: "Pre-installed" usually means out of the box the app is there (e.g. an assigned company phone) otherwise it is just "user installed". In any case if the app is a consumer app from the Play Store, everything Gautam said applies and you'll never be able to capture those users who don't update the app (until it breaks when you turn off old web server APIs) and hopefully are on newer phones with a more recent app.